# Using descriptors in unhashable classes - python

Tags: python, descriptor

A common design pattern when using python descriptors is to have the descriptor keep a dictionary of instances using that descriptor. For example, suppose I want to make an attribute that counts the number of times it's accessed:

```
class CountingAttribute(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.value = None


class MyDescriptor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.instances = {} #instance -> CountingAttribute

    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst in self.instances:
           ca = self.instances[inst]
        else:
            ca = CountingAttribute()
            self.instances[inst] = ca
        ca.count += 1
        return ca


class Foo(object):
    x = MyDescriptor()


def main():
    f = Foo()
    f.x
    f.x
    print("f.x has been accessed %d times (including the one in this print)"%(f.x.count,))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is a completely silly example that doesn't do anything useful; I'm trying to isolate the main point.

The problem is that I can't use this descriptor in a class which isn't hashable, because the line

```
self.instances[inst] = ca
```

uses instances as a dictionary key. Is there a wise way of handling this sort of case? For example, one immediately thinks to use the instance's `id`, but I'm not sure if doing that will break something about how hashes are supposed to be used.

EDIT: I realize that `instances` should be something like a `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary` but I'm trying to keep it simple here to focus on the issue of hashability.

Comment: My first thought was to try using a [`WeakKeyDictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary) for `instances`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to fix the underlying problem of unhashability, but it's a good idea nonetheless. (Otherwise, the descriptor would keep an otherwise-dead object alive.)

Comment: Yes, in my actual implementation I do use a WeakKeyDictionary. I didn't do that here because I am trying to keep the focus on the question at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `id(inst)` as a key.

Be aware that this doesn't cover the case that an object is destroyed and a new one is created with a new id.

In order to detect this properly, you should store the `ca` *and* a weakref in the dictionary. If you detect that the weakref's referred object is gone, you have to assume that the given id is reused.

Something like

```
import weakref

class MyDescriptor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.instances = {} #instance -> CountingAttribute

    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is None: return self.instances # operating on the class, we get the dictionary.
        i = id(inst)
        if i in self.instances:
            ca, wr = self.instances[i]
            if wr() is None: del self.instances[i]
        if i not in self.instances:
            ca = CountingAttribute()
            self.instances[i] = (ca, weakref.ref(inst))
        ca.count += 1
        return ca
```

This relieves from the hashability problems conntected to a `WeakKeyDictionary`.

But maybe you don't need the dict at all. A completely different approach could be

```
class MyDescriptor(object):

    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is None: return self, cls
        try:
            ca = inst.__the_ca
        except AttributeError:
            ca = inst.__the_ca = CountingAttribute()
        ca.count += 1
        return ca
```

This approach has its downsides as well. For example, you cannot easily use the descriptor more than once in a class without making it ugly as well. Thus, it should only be used with care. The first solution is, while more complex, the most uncomplicated one.

Comment: To what is the weak reference referring? :)

Comment: In the second version, you'd probably be wise to use the `__varname` private variable syntax, so that you won't accidentally break things if the class you're put in already has a `the_ca` attribute that means something else. So: `instance.__the_ca`. This is exactly the kind of thing the `__varname` syntax is for!

Comment: To be honest, I really don't like the second version. Having descriptors paste things onto the objects they manage seems... backwards. At the same time, I agree that with name mangling it's ok.

Comment: @DanielSank Both versions have their downsides. I don't like it so much as well, but it is simpler than the other.

Comment: @glglgl: A major problem with the second method is that you can't use the descriptor more than once in a class, because .__the_ca gets used by each one. This could be fixed by adding a label to each use of the descriptor, but now this gets ugly. This is an illustration of why I don't like descriptors pasting data onto the instances they manage, and a good reason to use the first method from your post.

Comment: @DanielSank Here I agree. I'll edit that into the post.