# How should instance data be handled in descriptors?

Tags: python, descriptor

A python descriptor frequently needs to associate data to each instance it manages. There are basically two ways to do this. The first is to paste the data onto each instance using a label which is nominally unique to the descriptor (possibly depending on other information):

```
class MyDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = make_label_based_on(label)

    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is not None:
            return getattr(inst, self.label)
        else:
            ...

    def __set__(self, inst, val):
        setattr(inst, self.label, val)
```

The other strategy is to store the data internally to the descriptor:

```
class MyDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is not None:
            return self.data[inst]
        else:
            ...

    def __set__(self, inst, val):
        self.data[inst] = val
```

Never mind the cases where a key is missing from `data`, or where the instances aren't hashable; that's not the point here and I [already know how to deal with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037479/using-descriptors-in-unhashable-classes-python).

My intuition says that the second strategy is much better because it less invasive into the managed instances. For example, it doesn't rely on unique attribute naming. I wonder if there are other considerations.

My question is: are there any considerations besides name collisions that one should take into account when choosing between these two strategies?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, but your first approach is a good situation to use Python's name mangling syntax: `def __get__(self, inst, cls): if inst is not None: return inst.__some_label` This assumes you'll never have more than one copy of your descriptor in a given class (which may or may not be a reasonable assumption).

Comment: @Blckknght: "This assumes you'll never have more than one copy of your descriptor in a given class" is a total show-stopper for me. Of course, one can use double-underscore name mangling *and* a user provided label. That's not the question though. My question specifically asked what considerations *besides* name collisions are important.

Comment: Yep, that's why that was a comment, not an answer. If you only need something very simple, name mangling can be very handy, but if you need more, it doesn't help much.